# Totally stuck on getting data from an access database, IIS 7 server 2008 PHP 5.4 Access 2010

Tags: php, ms-access, iis

I get no errors and output is as expected if it were a blank database, but there are well over 2500 rows in this database.

It also works fine under classic asp, which I am fluent at this is my first attempt at PHP. BTW the working asp site is on the same server so I now paths, security, drivers etc etc are all good. Unless there is some nuaince to just PHP.

Also I have spent hours (9 today) searching examples on google and specifically on this site. There are none that work out there that I can find, I'm sure it is one simple little missed overlooked syntax, as I am a 20+ year programmer with 172 IQ. Just my first attempt at PHP so please don't flame at me.

```
<?php include 'inc_top.php';
echo "<table align='center' width='900' border='3'>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "      <td align='center' style='width: 54px'><strong>ID</strong></td>";
echo "      <td align='center' style='width: 195px'><strong>Name</strong></td>";
echo "      <td align='center' style='width: 376px'><strong>Description</strong></td>";
echo "      <td align='center' style='width: 100px'><strong>Date</strong></td>";
echo "      <td align='center' style='width: 100px'><strong>Run Time</strong></td>";
echo "      <td align='center' style='width: 88px'><strong>Total Views</strong></td>";
echo "  </tr>";
{
$a = $_GET["selection"];
$count = 0;

$dbName = "c:\****\***\videos.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
   die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=c:\inetpub\database\winvideos.mdb");

$sql  = "SELECT * from video";
$result = $db->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch()); {

$video_name = $row["name"];
$video_desc = $row["desc"];
$video_date = $row["date"];
$video_views = $row["views"];
$video_runtime = $row["runtime"];
$video_id = $row["ID"];



echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>1" , $video_id, "</td>";
echo "<td>2" , $video_name, "</td>";
echo "<td>3" , $video_desc, "</td>";
echo "<td>4" , $video_date, "</td>";
echo "<td>5" , $video_runtime, "</td>";
echo "<td>6" , $video_views, "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$count = $count + 1;
}
print_r($row);

?>

</table>
<p> total count =<?php echo $count; ?></p
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Windows server you can save yourself some aggravation by using [COM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) and an `ADODB.Connection`. PHP simply does not work particularly well with Access ODBC. That is true whether you are using PDO_ODBC or the older `odbc_` PHP functions.

Note also that you *really* shouldn't be using an Access database to back a web application.

Comment: Been running the website under access for 10+ years, no problems, just have to code your asp to handle it..

Comment: Decided to just stay with classic asp. I miss the good ole usenet days when people were always on and help was everywhere.